# JqGrid local filter not working

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

The Below piece of code is not working for filter toolbar for local data.

Please help me to resolve this .
I am new to jqgrid. I am trying to make my grid to filter locally. The below piece of code is took from one of the example given in fiddle.

I am about to do the same thing, but what happens is ,I have two filters in my grid. If I select two filters then only the grid filters the data correctly. But if i select only one filter then the grid does not getting filter. Eventhough the value for the second filter is "no filter"

```
var serverResponse = [
    {id: 10,  label: 10, value: "Abc"},
    {id: 20,  label: 20, value: "Xyz"},
    {id: 30,  label: 30, value: "Abc"},
    {id: 40,  label: 40, value: "Xyz"},
    {id: 50,  label: 50, value: "Abc"},
    {id: 60,  label: 60, value: "Abc"},
    {id: 70,  label: 70, value: "Xyz"},
    {id: 80,  label: 90, value: "Abc"},
    {id: 90,  label: 10, value: "Xyz"},
    {id: 100, label: 20, value: "Abc"},
    {id: 110, label: 10, value: "Abc"},
    {id: 120, label: 30, value: "Xyz"},
    {id: 130, label: 10, value: "Abc"},
    {id: 140, label: 60, value: "Xyz"},
    {id: 150, label: 10, value: "Abc"}
];


$("#grid").jqGrid({
    url: "/echo/json/", // use JSFiddle echo service
    postData: {
        json: JSON.stringify(serverResponse) // needed for JSFiddle echo service
    },
    mtype: "POST", // needed for JSFiddle echo service
    datatype: "json",
    colNames: ["Label", "Value"],
    colModel: [
        {name: "label", width: 70, template: "integer" },
        {name: "value", width: 200 }    
    ],
    loadonce: true,
    pager: true,
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [5, 10, "10000:All"],
    iconSet: "fontAwesome",
    cmTemplate: { autoResizable: true },
    shrinkToFit: false,
    autoResizing: { compact: true },
    beforeProcessing: function (data) {
        var labelMap = {}, valueMap = {}, i, item, labels = ":All", values = [], $self = $(this);
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            item = data[i];
            if (!labelMap[item.label]) {
                labelMap[item.label] = true;
                labels += ";" + item.label + ":" + item.label;
            }
            if (!valueMap[item.value]) {
                valueMap[item.value] = true;
                values.push(item.value);
            }
        }
        $self.jqGrid("setColProp", "label", {
            stype: "select",
            searchoptions: {
                value: labels,
                sopt: ["eq"]
            }
        });
         $self.jqGrid("setColProp", "value", {
            stype: "select",
            searchoptions: {
                value: values,
                sopt: ["eq"]
            }
        });

        // one should use stringResult:true option additionally because
        // datatype: "json" at the moment, but one need use local filtreing later
        $self.jqGrid("filterToolbar", {stringResult: true });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all one can see that you get the code created for JFSiddle, which use Echo service of JSFiddle, and you try to use if whiteout JSFiddle. It's wrong. You should remove the references to Echo service if you need to use **local** data (`datatype: "local"`).

The corresponding code will look like

```js
$(function () {
    "use strict";
    var mydata = [
        {id: 10,  label: 10, value: "Abc"},
        {id: 20,  label: 20, value: "Xyz"},
        {id: 30,  label: 30, value: "Abc"},
        {id: 40,  label: 40, value: "Xyz"},
        {id: 50,  label: 50, value: "Abc"},
        {id: 60,  label: 60, value: "Abc"},
        {id: 70,  label: 70, value: "Xyz"},
        {id: 80,  label: 90, value: "Abc"},
        {id: 90,  label: 10, value: "Xyz"},
        {id: 100, label: 20, value: "Abc"},
        {id: 110, label: 10, value: "Abc"},
        {id: 120, label: 30, value: "Xyz"},
        {id: 130, label: 10, value: "Abc"},
        {id: 140, label: 60, value: "Xyz"},
        {id: 150, label: 10, value: "Abc"}
    ];

    $("#grid").jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        data: mydata,
        colNames: ["Label", "Value"],
        colModel: [
            {name: "label", width: 70, template: "integer" },
            {name: "value", width: 200 }    
        ],
        pager: true,
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [5, 10, "10000:All"],
        iconSet: "fontAwesome",
        cmTemplate: { autoResizable: true },
        shrinkToFit: false,
        autoResizing: { compact: true }
    }).jqGrid("filterToolbar");
});
```

See the demo https://jsfiddle.net/0bfnt8ym/

If you want to creates selects with unique values then you can do this *before* creating the grid:

```js
$(function () {
    "use strict";
    var mydata = [
        {id: 10,  label: 10, value: "Abc"},
        {id: 20,  label: 20, value: "Xyz"},
        {id: 30,  label: 30, value: "Abc"},
        {id: 40,  label: 40, value: "Xyz"},
        {id: 50,  label: 50, value: "Abc"},
        {id: 60,  label: 60, value: "Abc"},
        {id: 70,  label: 70, value: "Xyz"},
        {id: 80,  label: 90, value: "Abc"},
        {id: 90,  label: 10, value: "Xyz"},
        {id: 100, label: 20, value: "Abc"},
        {id: 110, label: 10, value: "Abc"},
        {id: 120, label: 30, value: "Xyz"},
        {id: 130, label: 10, value: "Abc"},
        {id: 140, label: 60, value: "Xyz"},
        {id: 150, label: 10, value: "Abc"}
    ],
    buildUniqueValues = function (data, propName) {
        var i, item, valueMap = {}, values = [":All"], dataLength = data.length, value, lowCaseValue;
        for (i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
            value = data[i][propName];
            if (value !== undefined) {
                lowCaseValue = typeof value === "string" ? value.toLowerCase() : value;
                if (valueMap[lowCaseValue] === undefined) {
                    valueMap[lowCaseValue] = lowCaseValue;
                    values.push(lowCaseValue + ":" + value);
                }
            }
        }
        return values.join(";");
    };

    $("#grid").jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        data: mydata,
        colNames: ["Label", "Value"],
        colModel: [
            { name: "label", width: 70, template: "integer",
                stype: "select",
                searchoptions: {
                    value: buildUniqueValues(mydata, "label"),
                    sopt: ["eq", "ne"]
                } },
            { name: "value", width: 200,stype: "select",
                searchoptions: {
                    value: buildUniqueValues(mydata, "value"),
                    sopt: ["eq", "ne"]
                } }    
        ],
        pager: true,
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [5, 10, "10000:All"],
        iconSet: "fontAwesome",
        cmTemplate: { autoResizable: true },
        shrinkToFit: false,
        autoResizing: { compact: true }
    }).jqGrid("filterToolbar");
});
```

See the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/0bfnt8ym/2/